# Manipulating raw IP addresses in "network" and confusion about byte order

Tags: haskell, networking, ip-address, endianness

The documentation for `HostAddress` and `HostAddress6` from the [network](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.2.1/docs/Network-Socket-Internal.html#t:HostAddress) package says:

```
-- | Network byte order.
type HostAddress = Word32

-- | Host byte order.
type HostAddress6 = (Word32, Word32, Word32, Word32)
```

What does this byte order actually mean? After all, `Word32` should be a number independent of host [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), endianness should matter only when (de)serializing it.

**My goal is given an IPv4 or IPv6 address to construct the correct `SockAddr` value.**

It seems that for `HostAddress` the byte order is flipped on little-endian architectures, as I `show $ SockAddrInet 0 0x0100007f` gives `"127.0.0.1:0"`. And `show $ SockAddrInet6 0 0 (0,0,0,1) 0` gives `"[::1]:0` so it seems there the byte order is correct. But currently I don't have the opportunity to test it on a big-endian architecture.

Comment: I guess they are in "serialized" format, as after C functions `htons, htoni,...` which "mangle" the bits to convert from host-endianness to network-endianness. They should have been `newtype`s, IMO. (Further, I really don't like a library which self-declares itself to be "semi-public". Internal modules should be opaque.)

Comment: @Petr Pudlák - Can you at least provide some feedback on my answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Note the announcement of the a [new network package](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haskell-cafe/16NHm09PZik/Bli-wzf7CAAJ) which now supports [conversions between HostAddresses and endian independent tuples](https://github.com/haskell/network/pull/210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Data.IP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iproute-1.7.0/docs/Data-IP.html) module looks like it addresses this.

Have a look at:

- [toHostAddress](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iproute-1.7.0/docs/Data-IP.html#v:toHostAddress)
- [toHostAddress6](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iproute-1.7.0/docs/Data-IP.html#v:toHostAddress6)

and the various ways of creating an IPv4 and IPv6 value.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I examined the package and it indeed looks good. My main concern is that t's part of a bigger package that my library would have to depend on unnecessarily. Also I'm somewhat unhappy with functions for (de)constructing `IPv4` and `IPv6` that they use lists instead of tuples (less type-safe), but I guess that's easy to fix with a pull request :).